# how to use of Event-scoped custom dimensions and metrics reporting

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics

Custom-parameter reporting has been changed with "Event-scoped custom dimensions and metrics reporting".

I added one event "Audio_Exercises" and "track_title" as parameter. Now I want to get report with track_title value under Audio_Exercises event.

I tried to add "track_title" under Custom Definitions > Custom metrics. But Nothing happening in original event "Audio_Exercises".

Can someone guide me to how to achieve this ?

[Screenshots of Custom Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWjmr.png)

Answer (score 3):

I think that there's a data mismatch issue here.

Basically, the **custom dimensions** are your parameters with **text value**, while the **custom metrics** are your parameters with **numeric value**. Note that the parameter will start to accumulate data after you register it on the console, so your previous data will not be included here. In addition, a report card or chart will be added on each event that will log the parameter.

Reference: Event-scoped [custom dimensions and metrics](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/10075209) reporting.